# Adding user data from google signin for flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

once again I am in need of your help. I'm trying to add my signed in user data to my firestore database, but its not uploading, or maybe I'm not calling or passing the function properly. Here below is my code for adding the user data I got from FlutterFire

```
class AddUser extends StatelessWidget {
final String uid;
final String email;
final String displayName;
final String photoURL;
final String phoneNumber;
final UserMetadata metadata;

AddUser(this.uid, this.email, this.displayName, this.photoURL,
  this.phoneNumber, this.metadata);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 // Create a CollectionReference called users that references the firestore collection
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

Future<void> addUser() {
  // Call the user's CollectionReference to add a new user
  return users
      .add({
        'uid': uid,
        'displayName': displayName,
        'email': email,
        'photoURL': photoURL,
        'phonenumber': phoneNumber,
        'metadata': metadata,
        'lastSeen': DateTime.now()
      })
      .then((value) => print("User Added"))
      .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add user: $error"));
  }
 }
}
```

And Below is my Login Page where I'm trying to Call/Pass the AddUser Function.

```
class Newloginpage extends StatefulWidget {
  String uid;
  String email;
  String displayName;
  String photoURL;
  String phoneNumber;
  UserMetadata metadata;

  @override
  _Newloginpage createState() =>
      _Newloginpage(uid, displayName, email, photoURL, phoneNumber, metadata);
}

class _Newloginpage extends State<Newloginpage> {
  final String uid;
  final String email;
  final String displayName;
  final String photoURL;
  final String phoneNumber;
  final UserMetadata metadata;

  StreamSubscription<User> loginStateSubscription;
  TextEditingController _emailController;
  TextEditingController _passwordController;

  _Newloginpage(this.uid, this.email, this.displayName, this.photoURL,
      this.phoneNumber, this.metadata);

  @override
  void initState() {
    var authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false);
    loginStateSubscription = authProvider.currentUser.listen((fbUser) {
      if (fbUser != null) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => IntroPage()));
      }
    });
    super.initState();

    Firebase.initializeApp();
    _emailController = TextEditingController(text: "");
    _passwordController = TextEditingController(text: "");
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    loginStateSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
          child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FadeAnimation(
                          1,
                          Text(
                            "Login",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 40),
                          )),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 30),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(50))),
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 40,
                          ),
                          FadeAnimation(
                              1.4,
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    boxShadow: [
                                      BoxShadow(
                                          color:
                                              Color.fromRGBO(84, 211, 194, .3),
                                          blurRadius: 20,
                                          offset: Offset(0, 10))
                                    ]),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Container(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          border: Border(
                                              bottom: BorderSide(
                                                  color: Colors.grey[200]))),
                                      child: TextField(
                                        controller: _emailController,
                                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                                            hintText: "Admin Use Only",
                                            hintStyle:
                                                TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                            border: InputBorder.none),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          border: Border(
                                              bottom: BorderSide(
                                                  color: Colors.grey[200]))),
                                      child: TextField(
                                        controller: _passwordController,
                                        obscureText: true,
                                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                                            hintText: "Admin Only",
                                            hintStyle:
                                                TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                            border: InputBorder.none),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 40,
                          ),
                          FadeAnimation(
                            4,
                            RoundedButton(
                              text: "Login",
                              press: () async {
                                if (_emailController.text.isEmpty ||
                                    _passwordController.text.isEmpty) {
                                  print("Email and password cannot be empty");
                                  return;
                                }
                                bool authResult = await AuthProvider()
                                    .signInWithEmail(_emailController.text,
                                        _passwordController.text);
                                if (!authResult) {
                                  print("Login failed");
                                }
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                          FadeAnimation(
                            2,
                            GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                AddUser(uid, displayName, email, photoURL,
                                    phoneNumber, metadata);
                              },
                              child: SignInButton(
                                Buttons.Google,
                                text: "Sign in with Google",
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  User authResult =
                                      await AuthProvider().signInWithGoogle();

                                  if (authResult != null) {
                                    print("Error logging in with Google");
                                  }
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
```

Below is my Log for when I initiate Google Sign In

```
W/ActivityThread( 7775): handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@240629d 
    
D/EGL_emulation( 7775): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1f1b9e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc9138170)
                   
    W/rus.moecya( 7775): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->compareAndSwapObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (greylist, linking, allowed) 
    
D/EGL_emulation( 7775): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe1f1b9e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc9138170) 
    
I/BiChannelGoogleApi( 7775): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzao@986c272 
    
    W/DynamiteModule(7775): Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found. 
            
    I/FirebaseAuth( 7775): [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation 
        
    D/FirebaseAuth( 7775): Notifying id token listeners about user fb347ty783oy7o34hui3q4f ). 
    
    D/FirebaseAuth( 7775): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( fb347ty783oy7o34hui3q4f ).
                   
    E/emuglGLESv2_enc( 7775): device/generic/goldfish opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glTexSubImage2D:2474 GL error 0x501 
        
    I/chatty  ( 7775): uid=10134(com.website.app) 1.io identical 7 lines
                   
    E/emuglGLESv2_enc( 7775): device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glTexSubImage2D:2474 GL error 0x501 
        
    W/ConnectionTracker( 7775): Exception thrown while unbinding 
    
    W/ConnectionTracker( 7775): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered:com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzji@df7a8be
                   
    W/ConnectionTracker( 7775): at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1751)
                   
    W/ConnectionTracker( 7775): at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1776)
                  
    W/ConnectionTracker( 7775): at               android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:741)
                   
    W/ConnectionTracker( 7775): at           com.google.android.gms.common.stats.ConnectionTracker.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.3.0:55)
                   
    W/ConnectionTracker( 7775):     at
                   com.google.android.gms.common.stats.ConnectionTracker.unbindService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.3.0:50)
                   
    W/ConnectionTracker( 7775):     at
                   com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzio.zzag(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:245)
                   
    W/ConnectionTracker( 7775):     at
                   com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzio.zzal(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:262)
                   
    W/ConnectionTracker( 7775):     at
                   com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzio.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:336)
                   
    W/ConnectionTracker( 7775):     at
                   com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzir.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:2)
                   
    W/ConnectionTracker( 7775):     at
                   com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzai.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:7)
                   
    W/ConnectionTracker( 7775):     at
                   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
                   
    W/ConnectionTracker( 7775):     at
                   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                   
    W/ConnectionTracker( 7775):     at
                   com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfs.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:21)
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Few flaws in this implementation,

- Don't push a route when you're logging in a user, listen to the `authState` inside your `ChangeNotifier` and update the view accordingly instead. This is a better approach and you shouldn't be pushing when the app is initializing.

```
AuthProvider with ChangeNotifier{

boolean isLoggedIn = false;

@override
initState(){
 authProvider.authState.listen((fbUser) {
      if (fbUser != null) {
       isLoggedIn = true;
       notifyListners();
      }else{
        isLoggedIn = false;
       notifyListners();

      }
    });
 super.initState();

}
```

and in your view,

```
class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget{

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);

    return  authProvider.isLoggedIn? Newloginpage(): IntroPage();
```

- `Firebase.initializeApp()` should be called when the app initializes and before you make a call to any other firebase service.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await  Firebase.initializeApp();
  ...
}
```

I believe this is what is causing the issue, try this out and let me know.

Comment: Its still not uploading the user information. I tried to add WidgetsFlutterBinding instead of FlutterWidgetsBinding, it was giving an error and I assumed it was a typo. Still no dice.            PS- Thanks for the input regarding FB, it wasnt working properly, thats why I removed the button, but I think you solved that for me as well.

Comment: @Doctor, I'm sorry, yes it was a typo. If you can tell me any of your logs,or give me some more context, I might be able to help you, I didn't find any thing else in the code.

Comment: I've updated the logs. Hope this could give some insight into the problem.

Comment: These logs are not related to your problem, what do the logs in your addUser function print out ? @Doctor